# App "failed to resume in time" and hangs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, abaddressbook

My app runs fine on my ipad but when I run it on my bosses ipad it hangs and stores the following device log, any ideas?

> Incident Identifier: 6C33511B-7C9A-474C-B888-84A4FAFF6F91
>   CrashReporter Key:   93bbba4f690eb1b7638fa7a09a3ff3aa4e6872f4 Hardware
>   Model:      iPad2,1 Process:         Designer [5279] Path:
>   /var/mobile/Applications/7AA5BF4A-007D-47F8-B1C5-30667477AA12/Designer.app/Designer
>   Identifier:      Designer Version:         ??? (???) Code Type:
>   ARM (Native) Parent Process:  launchd [1]
>
> Date/Time:       2011-10-19 13:29:29.907 +0100 OS Version:      iPhone
>   OS 5.0 (9A334) Report Version:  104
>
> Exception Type:  00000020 Exception Codes: 0x8badf00d Highlighted
>   Thread:  0
>
> Application Specific Information: Systems.Designer failed to resume in
>   time
>
> Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 0.000 (user 0.000, system 0.000), 0%
>   CPU  Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.002, 0% CPU
>
> Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread Thread 0: 0
>   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x307d1a3c memset$VARIANT$CortexA9 +
>   100 1   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x36cd3e7e 0x36cbf000 + 85630 2
>   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x36cc73ec 0x36cbf000 + 33772 3
>   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x36cc6c78 0x36cbf000 + 31864 4
>   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x36cc64a8 0x36cbf000 + 29864 5
>   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x36cc5f92 0x36cbf000 + 28562 6
>   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x36cc5ce8 0x36cbf000 + 27880 7
>   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x36cd29ea 0x36cbf000 + 80362 8
>   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x36cc5962 sqlite3_exec + 678 9
>   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x36cd273a 0x36cbf000 + 79674 10 
>   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x36cd228e 0x36cbf000 + 78478 11 
>   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x36cceebe 0x36cbf000 + 65214 12 
>   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x36ccb41a 0x36cbf000 + 50202 13 
>   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x36cc6c78 0x36cbf000 + 31864 14 
>   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x36cc6464 0x36cbf000 + 29796 15 
>   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x36cc5f92 0x36cbf000 + 28562 16 
>   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x36cc5ce8 0x36cbf000 + 27880 17 
>   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x36cfd094 sqlite3_prepare_v2 + 20 18 
>   AppSupport                        0x36efb8a4 CPSqlitePreparedStatement +
>   40 19  AppSupport                     0x36efbbde
>   CPSqliteConnectionStatementForSQLAndIgnoreErrors + 114 20  AppSupport 
>     0x36efc64e CPSqliteConnectionPerformSQL + 6 21  AppSupport
>     0x36efca44 _createConnectionForWriting + 360 22  AppSupport
>     0x36efcc06 _connectAndCheckVersion + 18 23  AppSupport
>     0x36efd0b8 CPSqliteDatabaseConnectionForWriting + 36 24  AppSupport
>     0x36efd18e CPSqliteDatabaseRegisterFunction + 14 25  AddressBook
>     0x324db6dc ABCDBContextCreateWithPathAndAddressBook + 208 26 
>   AddressBook                       0x324cf6fa
>   ABCCreateAddressBookWithDatabaseDirectoryAndForceInProcessMigrationInProcessLinkingAndResetSortKeys
>   + 226 27  AddressBook                     0x324ddf88 ABAddressBookCreate + 8 28  Designer                 0x000e222c
>   +[AddressBookModel createTableViewControllerItemFromABRecordID:] (AddressBookModel.m:15) 29  Designer                 0x000e1ee0
>   -[CustomPersonPickerViewController getAllContacts] (CustomPersonPickerViewController.m:56) 30  Designer
>     0x000e1d9c -[CustomPersonPickerViewController
>   initWithSelectedABRecordID:andSelectAnItemViewDelegate:]
>   (CustomPersonPickerViewController.m:28) 31  Designer
>     0x000dce56 -[EditEntityViewController editAccountable:]
>   (EditEntityViewController.m:96) 32  CoreFoundation
>     0x3522442e -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 46 33
>   UIKit                             0x375d19e4 -[UIApplication
>   sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 56 34  UIKit
>     0x375d19a0 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:]
>   + 24 35  UIKit                            0x375d197e -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 38 36  UIKit
>     0x375d16ee -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] +
>   486 37  UIKit                             0x375d131a -[UIControl
>   touchesBegan:withEvent:] + 238 38  UIKit
>     0x375d047e -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 174 39  UIKit
>     0x375cfefa -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 374 40  UIKit
>     0x375b64e6 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 350 41  UIKit
>     0x375b5d26 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5802 42  GraphicsServices
>     0x31d0be0c PurpleEventCallback + 876 43  CoreFoundation
>     0x3529e54c **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION**
>   + 32 44  CoreFoundation                   0x3529e4ee __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134 45  CoreFoundation                    0x3529d33c __CFRunLoopRun + 1364 46  CoreFoundation
>     0x352204d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294 47  CoreFoundation
>     0x3522039e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98 48  GraphicsServices
>     0x31d0afe6 GSEventRunModal + 150 49  UIKit
>     0x375e473c UIApplicationMain + 1084 50  Designer
>     0x000d4854 main (main.m:14) 51  Designer                0x000d480c
>   0xd3000 + 6156
>
> Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager Thread
>   1: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x303ff3b4 kevent + 24 1
>   libdispatch.dylib                 0x35b5ef74 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708 2
>   libdispatch.dylib                 0x35b5ec92 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30
>
> Thread 2 name:  WebThread Thread 2: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x3040f0d8 **psynch_mutexwait + 24 1   libsystem_c.dylib
>
>     0x3075ec44 pthread_mutex_lock + 376 2   WebCore
>
>     0x362f536c _ZL17_WebTryThreadLockb + 208 3   WebCore
>
>     0x362f5670 *ZL14WebRunLoopLockP19*_CFRunLoopObservermPv + 24 4
>
>   CoreFoundation                    0x3529eb44
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 12 5   CoreFoundation                 0x3529cd80 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 252
>   6   CoreFoundation                    0x3529d19a __CFRunLoopRun + 946 7
>   CoreFoundation                    0x352204d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294 8
>   CoreFoundation                    0x3522039e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98 9
>   WebCore                           0x36397128 _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 396 10
>   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x3076bc16 _pthread_start + 314 11 
>   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x3076bad0 thread_start + 0
>
> Unknown thread crashed with unknown flavor: 5, state_count: 1

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Whenever you see a `0x8badf00d` that means you are getting killed by the launch watchdog.  Your app is taking too long to return from `-applicationDidFinishLaunching...`.  Normal Core Data related causes to this are:

1. Trying to import data in the `-applicationDidFinishLaunching...`
2. Trying to perform a migration from `-applicationDidFinishLaunching...`

To solve this you need to change your start up.  The creating of the Core Data stack should never be done in the `-applicationDidFinishLaunching...`.  Instead let the `-applicationDidFinishLaunching...` finish and then stand up the Core Data stack.  If a migration is needed (you can check this pretty easily) then present the user with a UI informing them of the delay and then kick it off.

In either case you need to return from the `-applicationDidFinishLaunching...` as fast as possible, you should only be creating UI elements in this method; you should not be accessing Core Data at this point.

Comment: When you say up the core data stack, do you mean calling one of the generated methods e.g. managedObjectContext?  Also I am placing a view on the window, which requires data, so I need the core data

Comment: Yes, accessing the `NSManagedObjectContext` will create the Core Data stack.  It must be called after the `-applicationDidFinishLaunching...` has finished which means you will need to rework the launching of your application.  I suggest starting with a trace in instruments to find out *why* your application is taking so long to stand up the stack.

Comment: @NicolasManzini It's actually even funnier -- Ate bad food :)