# What is the possible cause of this crash?

Tags: ios, stack-trace

I realize that this is a bit of a vague question, but I'm looking for a place to start. I have testflight live running and am noticing the following crash:

```
0 Powercents 0x000781de testflight_backtrace + 142
1 Powercents 0x00078d6c TFSignalHandler + 212
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x319937ec _sigtramp + 48
3 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3198920e pthread_kill + 54
4 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3198229e abort + 94
5 AppSupport 0x35f70c2e abortAfterPassingIntegrityCheck + 38
6 AppSupport 0x35f70ee6 runIntegrityCheckAndAbort + 526
7 AppSupport 0x35f7102c checkResultWithStatement + 120
8 AppSupport 0x35f72a12 _connectAndCheckVersion + 1058
9 AppSupport 0x35f72ab6 CPSqliteDatabaseConnectionForWriting + 42
10 AppSupport 0x35f72b8c CPSqliteDatabaseRegisterFunction + 20
11 AddressBook 0x345523f6 ABCDBContextCreateWithPathAndAddressBook + 214
12 AddressBook 0x34546428 ABCCreateAddressBookWithDatabaseDirectoryAndForceInProcessMigrationInProcessLinkingAndResetSortKeys + 232
13 AddressBook 0x34554cd6 ABAddressBookCreate + 14
14 TextInput 0x377981c4 _ZN2KB45fill_with_matchable_strings_from_address_bookERNS_7HashmapINS_6StringEbEE + 16
15 TextInput 0x3779edf4 _ZN2KB21DynamicDictionaryImpl28background_load_address_bookERKNS_16StaticDictionaryE + 200
16 TextInput 0x3779f72e _ZN2KBL14BackgroundLoadEPv + 278
17 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3194a734 _pthread_start + 320
18 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3194a5ef thread_start + 7
```

It seems from what I can tell in testflight the crash happens right on opening the app.

Here is the applicationDidFinishLaunching code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{   
    NSDictionary *plistData = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
    MB_LOG_LEVEL = [[plistData valueForKey:@"MBLogLevel"] intValue];

    NSArray *versionParts = [[plistData objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

    self.versionString = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"version.string", nil),
                          [plistData objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"], 
                          // accounts for $Rev: 407 $
                          [versionParts objectAtIndex: ([versionParts count] > 1 ? 1 : 0)],
                          [plistData objectForKey:@"MBBuildDate"]
                          ];

    [self bootstrap];

    // TestFlight and Google Analytics
    [Tracking startup];

    // Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of the window
    // Note: Do it this way, since the UIWindow class has no rootViewController
    // property in iOS 3.x.
    [window_ addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];
    [window_ makeKeyWindow];

    // set up APNS with Urban Airship
    [self initAirship:launchOptions];

    // If it is the first time running the app, delete all local notifications
    [self cleanLocalNotifications];

    // Handle launching from a notification
    UILocalNotification *localNotif =
    [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    if (localNotif) {
        NSLog(@"Recieved Notification %@",localNotif);
    }    

    return YES;
}
```

And here is the bootstrap method:

```
- (void)bootstrap
{    
    // simple check for a bootstrapped db
    Settings *settings = (Settings*)[DataManager objectForEntity:NSStringFromClass([Settings class]) 
                                            sortDescriptorsOrNil:nil
                                                  predicateOrNil:nil];
    if (!settings) {
        settings = (Settings*)[DataManager createManagedInstance:NSStringFromClass([Settings class])];
        [settings setEnergyMobileFirstRun:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
        [settings setFirstRun:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
        [settings setShowWelcomeAlertView:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
        [settings setOnPeakAlertNotificationTime:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
        [settings setMidPeakAlertNotificationTime:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
        [settings setOffPeakAlertNotificationTime:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
        [settings setOnPeakAlertNotificationsActive:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
        [settings setMidPeakAlertNotificationsActive:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
        [settings setOffPeakAlertNotificationsActive:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
        [DataManager saveManagedInstances];
    }
    if ([settings.firstRun boolValue])
    {
        // Clear the Database
        [DataManager deleteAllObjectsForEntity:@"Appliance"];
        [DataManager deleteAllObjectsForEntity:@"Answer"];
        [DataManager deleteAllObjectsForEntity:@"AnsweredQuestion"];
        [DataManager deleteAllObjectsForEntity:@"Question"];
        [self loadSavingsTipData];
        [self createChecklistTips];
        [self initializeTimeOfUseBehaviour];
        [settings setFirstRun:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
        [DataManager saveManagedInstances];
    }
}
```

edited to add more info:

This stacktrace is coming from TestFlight live. The crash is from an app that has been purchased from the app store.

Here is the entire stacktrace:

```
    PRIMARY THREAD THREAD 10

0 Powercents 0x000781de testflight_backtrace + 142
1 Powercents 0x00078d6c TFSignalHandler + 212
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x319937ec _sigtramp + 48
3 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3198920e pthread_kill + 54
4 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3198229e abort + 94
5 AppSupport 0x35f70c2e abortAfterPassingIntegrityCheck + 38
6 AppSupport 0x35f70ee6 runIntegrityCheckAndAbort + 526
7 AppSupport 0x35f7102c checkResultWithStatement + 120
8 AppSupport 0x35f72a12 _connectAndCheckVersion + 1058
9 AppSupport 0x35f72ab6 CPSqliteDatabaseConnectionForWriting + 42
10 AppSupport 0x35f72b8c CPSqliteDatabaseRegisterFunction + 20
11 AddressBook 0x345523f6 ABCDBContextCreateWithPathAndAddressBook + 214
12 AddressBook 0x34546428 ABCCreateAddressBookWithDatabaseDirectoryAndForceInProcessMigrationInProcessLinkingAndResetSortKeys + 232
13 AddressBook 0x34554cd6 ABAddressBookCreate + 14
14 TextInput 0x377981c4 _ZN2KB45fill_with_matchable_strings_from_address_bookERNS_7HashmapINS_6StringEbEE + 16
15 TextInput 0x3779edf4 _ZN2KB21DynamicDictionaryImpl28background_load_address_bookERKNS_16StaticDictionaryE + 200
16 TextInput 0x3779f72e _ZN2KBL14BackgroundLoadEPv + 278
17 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3194a734 _pthread_start + 320
18 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3194a5ef thread_start + 7
Hide Other Threads

THREAD 1 COM.APPLE.NSURLCONNECTIONLOADER

0 CoreFoundation 0x3738f12a __CFRunLoopRun + 882
1 CoreFoundation 0x373124a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
2 CoreFoundation 0x3731236c CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
3 Foundation 0x37b67bb8 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 308
4 Foundation 0x37b67a80 -[NSThread main] + 72
5 Foundation 0x37bfb590 __NSThread__main__ + 1048
6 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3194a734 _pthread_start + 320
7 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3194a5ef thread_start + 7
THREAD 2 COM.APPLE.CFSOCKET.PRIVATE

0 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3194a5ef thread_start + 7
THREAD 3 THREAD 11

Empty Stacktrace

THREAD 4 WEBTHREAD

0 CoreFoundation 0x3738f12a __CFRunLoopRun + 882
1 CoreFoundation 0x373124a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
2 CoreFoundation 0x3731236c CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
3 WebCore 0x32fd20f6 _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 402
4 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3194a734 _pthread_start + 320
5 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3194a5ef thread_start + 7
THREAD 5 THREAD 8

0 CoreFoundation 0x3738f12a __CFRunLoopRun + 882
1 CoreFoundation 0x373124a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
2 CoreFoundation 0x3738f44a CFRunLoopRun + 98
3 Powercents 0x000a9f0a +[UA_ASIHTTPRequest runRequests] + 134
4 Foundation 0x37b67a80 -[NSThread main] + 72
5 Foundation 0x37bfb590 __NSThread__main__ + 1048
6 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3194a734 _pthread_start + 320
7 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3194a5ef thread_start + 7
THREAD 6 THREAD 12

Empty Stacktrace

THREAD 7 THREAD 0

0 CoreFoundation 0x3738f0f0 __CFRunLoopRun + 824
1 CoreFoundation 0x373124a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
2 CoreFoundation 0x3731236c CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
3 GraphicsServices 0x3221f438 GSEventRunModal + 136
4 UIKit 0x33a96e7c UIApplicationMain + 1080
5 Powercents 0x0004cfb2 main + 66
6 Powercents 0x0004cf6b start + 39
THREAD 8 THREAD 1

0 0xffffffff + 0
THREAD 9 THREAD 2

Empty Stacktrace

THREAD 10 THREAD 3

Empty Stacktrace

THREAD 11 THREAD 6

Empty Stacktrace

THREAD 12 THREAD 7

0 CoreFoundation 0x3738f12a __CFRunLoopRun + 882
1 CoreFoundation 0x373124a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
2 CoreFoundation 0x3731236c CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
3 Foundation 0x37b5bb74 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 256
4 Foundation 0x37b75522 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 78
5 Powercents 0x0008d25c -[TFNetworkManager networkRunLoopThreadEntry] + 72
6 Foundation 0x37b67a80 -[NSThread main] + 72
7 Foundation 0x37bfb590 __NSThread__main__ + 1048
8 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3194a734 _pthread_start + 320
9 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3194a5ef thread_start + 7
```

Comment: Is this live in he wild, or on your simulator, or on a device?  Is this app signed for appstore?

Comment: Conceptually the best way to find out what kind of error happened is to try to reproduce this error and debug it.

Comment: Well, I can't see a place where AddressBook is involved, but my guess is that one of 3rd-party SDKs is trying to get access to it. Try to search your project or workspace for "AddressBook" keywords (with different kinds of this query). Unfortunately SDKs packed in .a-libraries would not let you do this, so you can try to disable 3rd-party SDKs one by one and see if that crash happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure, but it seems to me that this answer deals with the same issue that I'm having:

[App "failed to resume in time" and hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7822988/472344)

Answer (score 4):

I am currently seeing an identical crash in Production on iOS 5.1 devices only. Although I'm not sure what is triggering the crash, I think it's safe to say this was an Apple bug that has been fixed in iOS 6.

Comment: Got one raised for my app and it was IOS 5.1 - we don't use address book - crashed 3 times on the day - must be a pretty bad bug

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me your application works with iOS Address Book. If you can debug your application, try to symulate this error on connection by changing Address Book API calls.

Comment: Thanks. I have worked with Address Book before, so I recognized that the framework was being called. The strange thing is though that I'm not using it in this app, and the Framework isn't even included!

Comment: Darren, can you please post your application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method from AppDelegate?

Comment: I posted the method, and the bootstrap method that is called in it. There are more methods called in the bootstrap method, but it is starting to be too much code to post. I suspect that the problem might occur with migrating the Core Data data base after someone upgrades the app. What was really confusing me though was the Address Book calls. I can't understand why they are there.

Answer (score 1):

It looks AddressBook related - do post the entire crash report.

Looks as if the AddressBook API was being initialized and an error occurred while opening the supporting sqlLite database. Perhaps connectAndCheckVersion fails in some way.

TestFlight is only there because it installs a catch-all signal handler to report the app crashes to TestFlight Live.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by post the entire crash report, but I posted all the information that I'm getting from the TestFlight live site. As I mentioned in another comment, I'm not using AddressBook (at least to my knowledge!) in this app. I haven't included the framework. I am using a number of other libraries (Urban Airship, TestFlight, Google Analytics, Facebook) so I don't know if one of those might possibly be trying to call the address book methods?

Comment: TestFlight and Facebook don't use Address Book for sure. Maybe Urban Airship or Google Analytics? :)

Comment: I'm using Urban Airship and TestFlight haven't seen anything that looks like that crash. Ok, I thought you had the crash in xCode - is there a "Reason" listed in TestFlight Live?

Comment: No, it just says SIGBART and then there are the crash logs that I posted.