# SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags cause crash?

Tags: ios, networking, crash

I use SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags to get Net Flags, I used to work well.
But sometimes(not normallly) it case crash on the new ipad.
Here is call crash log:

> CrashReporter Key:   33f4ab575102aa60283b0dea73af84fbf45cb760 Hardware
>   Model:      iPad3,3
>
> Code Type:       ARM (Native) Parent Process:  launchd [1]
>
> Date/Time:       2012-08-31 15:38:09.338 +0800 OS Version:      iPhone
>   OS 5.1.1 (9B206) Report Version:  104
>
> Exception Type:  00000020 Exception Codes: 0x8badf00d Highlighted
>   Thread:  0
>
> Application Specific Information: com.oohla.HuaShangNews failed to
>   launch in time
>
> Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 2.120 (user 2.120, system 0.000),
>   14% CPU  Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.024, 0% CPU
>
> Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread Thread 0: 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x350ca054 semaphore_wait_trap + 8 1
>   libdispatch.dylib                 0x3132f1c0
>   _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 184 2   libdispatch.dylib                 0x3132f1f4 dispatch_semaphore_wait$VARIANT$mp + 32 3   libxpc.dylib
>     0x3058f89a xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync + 206 4
>   SystemConfiguration               0x36d18be6 _reach_server_target_status
>   + 938 5   SystemConfiguration             0x36d19d56 **SCNetworkReachabilityServer_targetStatus + 14 6   SystemConfiguration              0x36d02aee
>   __SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags + 198 7   SystemConfiguration             0x36d03f7a SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags + 190 8   HuaShangQ_iPhone
>
>     0x0005ed14 -[Reachability currentReachabilityStatus] + 152 9
>
>   HuaShangQ_iPhone                  0x000f39b4 -[HSStatManager
>   getCurrntNet] + 52 10  HuaShangQ_iPhone               0x000f2b6e
>   -[HSStatManager startSystem] + 322 11  HuaShangQ_iPhone               0x000f2068 -[HSStatManager entry] + 216 12  HuaShangQ_iPhone
>
>     0x0000dc6a -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]
>   (AppDelegate.m:47) 13  UIKit                          0x35142ca4
>   -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1176 14  UIKit                           0x3513c7d6 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 402 15  UIKit                           0x3510aabc -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1004 16  UIKit
>
>     0x3510a560 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 48 17  UIKit
>
>     0x35109f34 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5820 18  GraphicsServices
>
>     0x32ca7224 PurpleEventCallback + 876 19  CoreFoundation
>
>     0x32bd751c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION**
>   + 32 20  CoreFoundation                   0x32bd74be __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134 21  CoreFoundation                    0x32bd630c __CFRunLoopRun + 1364 22  CoreFoundation
>     0x32b5949e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294 23  CoreFoundation
>     0x32b59366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98 24  UIKit
>     0x3513b864 -[UIApplication _run] + 544 25  UIKit
>     0x35138cce UIApplicationMain + 1074 26  HuaShangQ_iPhone
>     0x0000e520 main (main.m:17) 27  HuaShangQ_iPhone
>     0x00003310 start + 32

How to avoid 
Help Plz.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to investigate this post [related to 0x8badf00d and  application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822988/app-failed-to-resume-in-time-and-hangs) since the crash ASI indicates that your app **failed to launch in time**.